# How to get the value of a specific properties parameter in a collection of Custom object using multiple where clause in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following list:

```
List<Product> productList = new List<Product>
      {
      new Product(){ Name = "C", OriginYear=1992,DevelopementYear=1992,IValue=110},
      new Product(){ Name = "C", OriginYear=1992,DevelopementYear=1993,IValue=170},
      new Product(){ Name = "C", OriginYear=1993,DevelopementYear=1993,IValue=200},
      new Product(){ Name = "NC", OriginYear=1990,DevelopementYear=1990,IValue=45.2M},
      new Product(){ Name = "NC", OriginYear=1990,DevelopementYear=1991,IValue=64.8M},
      new Product(){ Name = "NC", OriginYear=1990,DevelopementYear=1993,IValue=37.0M},
      new Product(){ Name = "NC", OriginYear=1991,DevelopementYear=1991,IValue=50},
      new Product(){ Name = "NC", OriginYear=1991,DevelopementYear=1992,IValue=75},
      new Product(){ Name = "NC", OriginYear=1991,DevelopementYear=1993,IValue=25},
      new Product(){ Name = "NC", OriginYear=1992,DevelopementYear=1992,IValue=55},
      new Product(){ Name = "NC", OriginYear=1992,DevelopementYear=1993,IValue=85},
      new Product(){ Name = "NC", OriginYear=1993,DevelopementYear=1993,IValue=100}
      };
```

Now I want to get the IValue of the Product which is having OriginYear=1992 and DevelopementYear=1992.
This is my query:

```
var temp = productList.Where(p => p.Name == "C").Where(p => p.OriginYear == 1992).Where(p => p.DevelopementYear == 1992).Select(p=>p.IValue);
```

Its returning 0.
However, if I check:

```
  new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView<decimal>(temp).Items[0]
```

It is giving desired value.(110)
May I know whats going on?How can I improve the query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The query you posted will return a sequence with a single element, where that element is `110`. It is not clear what you mean by _"its [sic] returning 0"_, nor why you think you ought to get an element having the value `170` instead. If you want an answer, fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: yes,I mean 110.

Comment: returning 0 means the value of temp=0 I am getting.

Comment: I basically need to get the value 110.

Comment: Assuming the `Product` class just stores the assigned value for `IValue`, the code you posted above will do that. So, copy and paste the code _you're actually using_. No one can help you if you hide the relevant details.

Comment: I have posted the code I am actually using... it should work, that's my understanding, not able to figure out why it's not working, that's why posted this question at the first place! :)

Comment: `Select` doesn't return a value. You can add `.First()` or `.Sum()` or `.Average()` or `.Count()` etc..  after it to get a value

Comment: _"I have posted the code I am actually using"_ -- no, you haven't. First, it's not a [mcve]. Second, you haven't shown _anything_ that would display or otherwise evaluate the result of your query. Again: it is not possible to explain to you what you've done wrong if you refuse to provide all the details.

Comment: Correct Slai,Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Select returns an `IEnumerable<T>` and you can iterate through it by using foreach

```
var temp = productList.Where(p => p.Name == "C" && p.OriginYear == 1992 && p.DevelopementYear == 1992).Select(p => p.IValue);

foreach(var t in temp)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

Or you can create a List or an array object out of it if you want to reach an individual element by using an index value

```
var temp = productList.Where(p => p.Name == "C" && p.OriginYear == 1992 && p.DevelopementYear == 1992).Select(p => p.IValue).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(temp[0]);
```